# A PL/SQL IDE with GIT support

Tags: git, ide, plsql, jdeveloper

I'm currently developing PL/SQL stored procedures for my company and I'd like to use a code revision control system to keep track of changes that other developers and I make. I like GIT for all its merits including distributed scm capabilities. Is there any IDE for PL/SQL development which supports GIT? Currently, I'm using JDeveloper because it also allows me to work on Java projects at the same time but I haven't been able to find a good GIT extension for it. Is there any chance that JDeveloper will officially support GIT in the future?

Thanks.

Comment: You really should learn (and love) using `git` from command line. This will allow you to better understand what is going on and how `git` works.

Comment: That's what I've thought of doing when I decided to use git to keep track of my source code but at my company we need to define a company-wide policy for a revision control tool which is integrated into an ide.

Comment: I would interpret that policy as "a revision control tool which **can be** integrated into an ide." But, maybe your company is more restrictive.

Comment: Maybe my company is restrictive but what we'd like to do is to adopt an IDE with revision control support to make life easy for everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider usage of [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) which is great IDE for Java, have git support out of the box and there is [SQL Code Assistant](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=4486) plugin (supporting PL/SQL)

There is JDeveloper plugin for git in early stages of development (currently only cloning of repositories is implemented) on http://mdlwr.amr-gawish.com/jdeveloper-git-plugin, you can follow development process and see how it goes...

Comment: Thanks for your information Juicy Scripter. I guess IntelliJ IDEA is a paid IDE. The JDeveloper plugin could be useful, though.

Comment: Yep, it is commercial (IMO worth every penny) but Community Edition (which is obviously free) also exists.

Comment: Yeah I know that IntelliJ is value for money but it's up to the boss to pay. Does the community edition include the SQL plugin?

Comment: None of them include plugin out of the box, but it can be simply installed on both.

Answer (score 2):

We built a small utility that hooks Git to the Oracle database. It is not an IDE but it will help you to perform common version control tasks using Git and it will automatically update your PL/SQL code base in the database. You can download it at [www.gitora.com](http://www.gitora.com)